# Issues texture painting an asset in cycles after applying Texture Atlas

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I've working off a tutorial where I've created a texture atlas for a helmet and now the next step is to start texture painting. When I swap over to texture paint mode, I cant apply paint and I cant figure out whats going on. Image link is posted below. I'm working in Cycles. Would appreciate any help, this is driving me mad

[image: screenshot-texture-paint]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3J1h.jpg

Comment: Your brush is set to Subtract mode, try switching it to Mix (as your image is black i.e. 0 subtracting. from it won't have any effect). And the image isn't shown in the UV editor so you won't see in the editor what is drawn, only on th emesh.

Comment: I gave that a shot but still nothing. I tried the add brush as well but that didnt do anything either :(

Comment: When i looking your picture it's obvious you din't create a texture first and plug it in node editor for cycles. i'll will link a tutorial how to proceed[Texture Painting | Quick start for cycles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcCQKuWPhXk)

Comment: Already took care of the node editor when this post was created. Node editor is hooked up yet still can't texture paint http://imgur.com/a/NBJah

Comment: For anyone else who has this issue and stumbles upon this thread, I figured it out. Under the stroke options of the texture paint menu, I had the stroke method set to CURVE. Changing it to SPACE fixed the issue entirely.    http://imgur.com/a/NBJah